# Not getting JSON from wordpress

Tags: php, android, json, wordpress

I am trying to make an android app for a wordpress website. But unable to get the JSON of post. I tried with two plugins[These are the plugins of the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VcR7.jpg)
for JSON

1. WP Rest API
2. JSON API

WP Rest API is returning this

```
[]
```

and JSON API is returning this

```
    {
  "status": "ok",
  "count": 0,
  "pages": 0,
  "category": {
    "id": 21,
    "slug": "maths",
    "title": "Maths",
    "description": "",
    "parent": 13,
    "post_count": 3
  },
  "posts": []
}
```

According to me this problem is due to any other plugin. But I am unable to find the solution

API using for JSON
1. with JSON API plugin I am using this link http://iitianlogic.com/custom/get_category_posts/
and posting id=4

Comment: Can you update the question with the code you are using to request the JSON?

Answer (score 1):

The request url is not correct, Please try the below url which showing posts under **uncategorized** category `http://iitianlogic.com/api/core/get_category_posts/?slug=uncategorized`

Hope this will work

Comment: Also you can try like this : http://iitianlogic.com/api/core/get_category_posts/?category_id=4 Please add post type if you have that [ &post_type=<your post type> ]